# WIX error re: user and message queue permissions (duplicate)

Tags: permissions, wix, message-queue

I'm learning WIX and I want to add permissions to the message queues that our existing installer created, so as to not have to set them manually after the installer runs.

I've got this snippet of code, and I can't figure out why it's causing an error like Duplicate symbol 'User:UserAnonymousLogon' found.

```
<util:User Id="UserLocalService" CreateUser="no" Name="LOCAL SERVICE"/>
<util:User Id="UserEveryone" CreateUser="no" Name="Everyone"/>
<util:User Id="UserAnonymousLogon" CreateUser="no" Name="ANONYMOUS LOGON"/>

<msmq:MessageQueue Id="AutoAssignMQ" Label="autoassignqueue" PathName=".\Private$\autoassignqueue">
<msmq:MessageQueuePermission Id="LocalServiceFull" User="UserLocalService" QueueGenericAll="yes"/>
<msmq:MessageQueuePermission Id="EveryoneLimited" User="UserEveryone" ReceiveMessage="yes" PeekMessage="yes" ReceiveJournalMessage="yes" GetQueueProperties="yes" GetQueuePermissions="yes" WriteMessage="yes"/>
<msmq:MessageQueuePermission Id="AnonymousLimited" User="UserAnonymousLogon" GetQueueProperties="yes" GetQueuePermissions="yes" WriteMessage="yes"/>
</msmq:MessageQueue>
```

This error appears twice for each file in the project that also have this snippet of code, but with different MessageQueue IDs. The util:User Id is repeated in many files, as are the msmq:MessageQueuePermission Id and User - do they have to be unique per file or something like that?

I'd like to know more but I'm not finding anything I understand to be about this. Please enlighten me on how to do this the correct way.

Answer (score 1):

I avoided the errors by using unique User IDs, and MessageQueue Ids. It didn't strike me as an optimal solution and therefor I'm still curious how others would have done it, but it works.